# How to move ClearCase license server from Solaris to Windows

Tags: clearcase

We have ClearCase license server installed in Solaris machine which is a very old machine. So our IT department want to stop using this machine and asked us to move the ClearCase license server to somewhere else. So we have installed the Clear Case license server & license administrator in Windows machine. Now we need to move the already existing licenses(300 in number) from Solaris box to windows. Can we do so? what is the procedure to do that? One more thing is now we are supposed to use only 22 of that 300 licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the procedure described in "[How to move licenses to a new server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308308)".

You need to release and re-assign licenses through the **[Rational License Key Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/support/licensing/)** you can [log in there](https://licensing.subscribenet.com/control/ibmr/login)).
You will be able to assign only the number of licenses you need for the new license server.